# onPostExecute does not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am working on android app and facing a problem. The problem is that onPostExecute does not execute everytime event doInBackground execute successfully and return true. My code is given below. Please help me I am in big trouble.

```
class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        msgtouser.setText("Wait we are fetching HOT DEALS...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Boolean retValue = false;

        try {

            HttpResponse response = null;
            String CSRFTOKEN = "";

            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // Access POST route using CSRFTOKEN
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_token", CSRFTOKEN));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", urls[1]));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                ccode.ErrorReporting(e);
            }

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("hotdeal");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    HotDeals objHD = new HotDeals();

                    objHD.setId(object.getInt("offid"));
                    objHD.setName(object.getString("line1"));
                    objHD.setLocation(object.getString("line3"));
                    objHD.setDistance(object.getString("dist"));
                    objHD.setOffer(object.getString("line2"));
                    objHD.setImage(object.getString("ban"));

                    dealsList.add(objHD);
                }

                retValue = true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ccode.ErrorReporting(e);
        }

        return retValue;
    }

     @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        dialog.cancel();
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (result == false && AppConstants.ISDEBUG) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Hot Deals : Network Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            if (dealsList.isEmpty()) {                  
                msgtouser.setText("Sorry, there are no HOT DEALS for the location selected by you");                    
            } else {
                msgtouser.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ListView listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listhd);
                adapter = new HotDealsAdapter(HotDealsFragment.this.getActivity(), R.layout.hotdeals_row,
                        dealsList);

                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know `onPostExecute()` did not get called?

Comment: hi is the dialog cancelled  after you do the task

Comment: The return types mentioned for your AsyncTask in  `AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>` is `String`,`Void` and `Boolean`. But the return types you have specified while defining the functions are `Void`, `Boolean` and `Boolean`, which is wrong. You should have `String`.`Void` and `Boolean` as specified in the AsyncTask declaration.

Comment: Log the result value in `onPostExecute()` method and check whether its showing the result value or not.

Comment: Don't wanna complain but you should really clean up this code... Why do you have two try-catch blocks inside each other? They do the same thing. Also we don't know half the variables here or what you're doing with them.  Also it would be good to see how you call this asynctask because that also matters.

Comment: you are canceling a dialog on `onPostExecute()`. Where are you initiating that?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call super.onPostExecute() (not sure if it could be causing problems, but isn't needed)  If this isn't the problem then below...

---

I "think" I know what the problem is... and we've ran into it before... IF this is happening when you rotate the phone (or any other hardware change)...

Then the problem is that the return value of the `doInBackground()` doesn't get actually passed to the `onPostExecute()` and you will get a null passed in. (if the hardware change happened during the `doInBackground()`)

However, that doesn't appear to be 'exactly' what you are having from your description. 'onPostExecute()' not running at all is odd. You should put a logcat statement as the very first thing in the method and see if that gets logged.

Because 'false' is the default value of `boolean` so it could be what you are describing where you don't have the 'else' part ever run, but you should be getting the toast then...

So log in two places (1) just before the return of doInBackground and (2) at the very beginning of the onPostExecute() and see if the values 'agree'

Comment: Do you think that this should be an answer?It should just be a comment to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I gave an answer, and a possible 2nd answer(if they are rotating the phone), and a suggestion on how to evaluate what the problem might be.(if those aren't the problem)